# Attend the lectures on some language

Tags: prepositions

I am writing something and I was curious, because I am not sure about the use of the preposition "on" in the following context.

"I attended lectures on the Portuguese language for two semesters at the University of Colorado" meaning, that I attended lectures about this language, and not that Portuguese was the language of instructions. Is the use of the preposition "on" in this context suitable or not? Is there another way to say this sentence?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. In this context, *on* means *about*.

Answer (score 1):

> ..lectures **on** the Portuguese language..

means the lectures are about that language.

> ..lectures **in** the Portuguese language..

means the lectures were about some topic but presented in the Portugese language.

Hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I knew that, but when I put it down on paper, it seemed a bit unusual for me, that's why I asked.